# how to fix Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, react-bootstrap, npm-scripts

I wanted to install Parallelshell but this warning keeps on coming
i have checked the package file but no solution .
can anyone help me through this?

Comment: This is optional dependency. Just ignore the message.

Answer (score 1):

i searched about it and found that
the module fsevents is a additional module for mac users .
it has nothing to do with windows and it causes no problem while coding
i was trying to minimize the warnings before deploying my website .

thanks for help @yury tarabanko